# How to get xml elements from xml file into list or dictionary based on conditions using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have xml file and I want to convert it's element into a list or dictionary anything based on condition.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<setdefine version="8.0">
<set>
    <name>Animal</name>
    <val>Tiger</val>
    <val>Lion</val>
</set>
<set>
    <name>Birds</name>
    <val>Eagle</val>
    <val>Ostrich</val>
</set>
</setdefine>
```

I want to create a list or dictionary by parsing this xml which contains only birds.
Output should be like:-
Birds : ['Eagle','Ostrich']
or
['Eagle','Ostrich']

Till now what I coded was :-

```
root = ElementTree.parse("xyz.xml")
birdlist = [] 
for child in root.iter('name'):
    print(child.text)
    if child.text == 'Birds':
    //here I am stuck what to do
        birdlist.append(child.text)
```

Please suggest, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try XPath instead of `.iter()`: `./set[name='Birds']/val`

Comment: thanks @Tomalak seems fixes my stuff